# How to block plugin activations with no known user or coming from unknown IP address range?

Tags: plugins, security, activation

I have received a Sucuri alert for an unauthorized plugin activation:
Event: Plugin Activated Website: http://www.XXXXXX.XXX IP Address: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX Reverse IP: XXXXXX.XXXXXX.XXXX Date/Time: 7 January 2021 5:00 PM Message: Plugin activated: Wp Zzz

How can I stop this happening?

Compared to a legitimate activation:

- Here there is no admin username specified (I guess nobody has logged in from the admin interface)
- The source IP address is not my home or office (this IP address keeps changing every time I get this Sucuri alert)

I appreciate all suggestions in advance.

Comment: Please consult the appropriate support forum for the plugin - https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/sucuri-scanner/.